# ios7 keyboard, when it opens shrinks web-app

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, keyboard, ios7

I have a web-app for iPad. The app uses the iPad keyboard, before when opening the keyboard it would cover the app, now with ios7 the app gets shrinked to the remaining space after the keyboard appears.

Is it possible to change this in JavaScript, and keep the old behavior?

**EDIT:** I just noticed that if I open the app on safari it works just like before, the problem appears when I add the app to the main screen.

**EDIT:** I almost solved this, but then I got some other problems.

First I added this **height=device-height** to the meta tag I was using:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

But then a small part of my app (the size of the iPad top bar) would be hidden at the bottom. So I did this:

```
$("#my_app").css("height",window.innerHeight);
```

When I opened the app again it was perfect. But when I open the keyboard, it moves up and wont come down when I close the keyboard. So now at the bottom of the iPad is a black line, and the app is a little bit hidden under the top bar of the iPad.

Can any one help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution ended up being very simple.

I removed this `height=device-height` again, and just left this `$("#my_app").css("height",window.innerHeight);` and every thing was fine again.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, height=1004">
```

hello I am Spanish and I do not speak English well. My solution has been to the highest in pixels (1004)