# iPad web app viewport height changes on orientation change when keyboard is active

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, web-applications

I have an iPad web app running iOS7. The viewport meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalabe=no">
```

On load and orientation change, I'm defining the height so that when the keyboard is active it doesn't scale the viewport height. The trick that was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914330/ios7-keyboard-when-it-opens-shrinks-web-app).

```
$('body, #canvas').css('height',window.innerHeight);
```

The problem though is when the keyboard is active and orientation changes, the viewport then changes to a value of the VISIBLE viewport area (not the viewport height when the keyboard is not active)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to define the height as a pixel value by first getting the available width and hight values of the device then simply calculate the orientation and setting my elements accordingly.

```
var deviceHeight = screen.availHeight;
var deviceWidth = screen.availWidth;

if(window.orientation > 0) {
    // landscape 
    $('body, #canvas').css('height',deviceWidth);
} else {
    // portrait
    $('body, #canvas').css('height',deviceHeight);
}
```

Not the most elegant solution but so far, so good.